# How to convert columns to row using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

How to convert rows as columns for a grouped output for a data.

Input (`Agent` and `order_date_week` are the index):

```
                       Average_Rating_Per_Week
Agent order_date_week                         
Abi   26                                   4.5
      27                                   5
      28                                   3.8
      29                                   4.0
      30                                   3.9
```

Output should be like this:

```
Agent  26    27   28    29    30 
Abi    4.5   5    3.8   4.0   3.9
```

like this I have 60 agents

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you already tried? For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the column and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df9['Average_Rating_Per_Week'].unstack('order_date_week')
```